# Oracle 19c Automatic Indexing

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, oracle19c

It seems Oracle automatic indexing feature that was introduced in Oracle 19c works only on Oracle Cloud and not AWS RDS.

Is my understanding correct (that AWS RDS doesn't support it)?

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-0F9EB85D-4610-4EDF-89C2-4916A0E7AC87

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/oracle-to-aurora-postgresql-migration-playbook/chap-oracle-aurora-pg.tables.autoindex.html. nope, not correct!

Comment: We get this error when we try in RDS which is Oracle enterprise version of 19c:      `ORA-40216: feature not supported
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AUTO_INDEX_INTERNAL", line 9994
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AUTO_INDEX", line 301
ORA-06512: at line 2`

Comment: Seems like you need to turn on some features. Check https://marcelo-ochoa.medium.com/some-features-requires-exadata-feature-on-true-for-example-248d2a965fd8 to get an idea of which paramters to modify.

Comment: Yes but that's only for test environment and not recommended for production as its meant for testing only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct.
Automatic Indexing is not supported on Amazon RDS.
Automatic Indexing works only on Oracle Database Enterprise Edition (19c+) when the database is hosted on an Oracle Engineered System (an Exadata machine). Such a system can be an Oracle Exadata machine on premises or sitting in the Oracle Pubic Cloud (using the Exadata Cloud Service or the Autonomous Database Service)